# Subclipse and Tortoise SVN together

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, plugins

Can these two SVN clients collaborate? I have my projects checked out with Tortoise, but now I would like to be able to use the SVN functionality (mostly updating and committing) from inside Eclipse. But the Subcipse doesn't see the SVN status of the files checked out by Tortoise.

I'm doing similar with Tortoise and MSVS plugin Ankh SVN and it works great. But now I need it to work in Eclipse...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you check code out of Subversion to create a "sandbox", the directories all contain meta-data in the .svn directory.  Any client you try to use against the "sandbox" will (assuming the client version is not behind the server), read the meta-data and understand the state of the sandbox and how to manage it with respect to the server.

So ... Yes, it will work just fine;)

Comment: Ah,I see. The problem is when not whole project including its root, but only some of the folders have the .svn data :(

Is here a way how to make the svn work only in these folders?

Comment: If you add them to the project, either client will create a .svn folder with the required meta-data and then the other client will recognize it as a "sandbox" folder.  If you don't want to add it to the project, set it to ignore and that meta-data will be saved in the parent folders .svn data.

Answer (score 7):

They work great together.

The one caveat: Make sure they're both using the same underlying subversion revision!  Subversion updates it's directories and reformats the .svn directories the first time you run a revision with major updates.  What this means is that when you upgrade you have to be careful that both subeclipse and tortoise have released new versions with the matching underlying subversion updates.

Since I've been using both, there have been two updates that break the compatability with the underlying .svn directories, so do be careful!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me. Always update both to the latest version, since there might be a problem if the files created by a specific client are incompatible with an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

Watchout for versions as mentioned before. For example Tortoise (1.8.2) requires Subversion 1.10 at Eclipse side. Update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x