# How to make Subeclipse recognize the projects checked out by TortoiseSVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN to checkout a directory from SVN which has many sub directories for different projects. Now when I import these sub directory projects into eclipse, the Subeclipse doesn't recognize these as versioned directories. How can I fix this so that I can use Eclipse to commit files?

I also observed that if I import the main directory into eclipse, the Subeclipse plugin is recognizing the versioning. I understand this is because there is a .svn folder in the main directory.

I am using 
Tortoise SVN version 1.7.10
Subeclipse version 1.10.0
My svn repository version is 1.6.15

I saw the below discussion in Stack overflow. But it doesnt answer my question. Please help.

[Subclipse and Tortoise SVN together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362784/subclipse-and-tortoise-svn-together)

Answer (score 0):

Subversions clients user a certain working copy format and if these two working copy format versions do not match then you will get a result where one client software won't recognize the other.

TortoiseSVN 1.7.10 uses the 1.7.7 working copy format and Subclipse 1.10.0 supports 1.8.x working copy format. Since these do no match you need to make sure they use the same. I would assume that the easiest for you is to download and install the latest version of TortoiseSVN (currently 1.8.2) as it supports the 1.8.3 working copy format.

If you still have problems after the upgrade, upgrade your working copy format version by issuing a `svn upgrade` command.

Comment: But, as I mentioned in the question, Subeclipse recognizes the versioning when I import the main directory. Also once it imports, it asks whether to upgrade the version. So Subeclipse is recognizing the older version directories checkedout by Tortoise. But the only problem is that this doesnt happen on the sub directories.